# SphinxQL jdbc как использовать

Tags: java, jdbc, sphinx, sphinxsearch

Настроил sphinx , проиндексировал. В общем все работает , но только через консоль.[image] Idea не воспринимает  SphinxQL синтаксис, как сделать этот запрос?[image]

Comment: А запрос-то сам проходит? То, что IDE не понимает SphinxQL не значит же, что вообще ничего работать не будет.

Comment: @Manticore Search запрос выполняется только через консоль, а в Idea не выполняется и выкидывает ExceptionInitializerError, там на скрине видно

Comment: ну это же Idea выкиывает, а не Java? Саму программу если запустить вообще без Idea, то работает?

Comment: @Manticore Search , я уже разобрался, ошибка была не из-за запроса. После этого я обрадовался, и сидел ещё 10 часов пытался настроить это все в спринге) . Соединение со сфинкс работает только на старых версиях MySQL коннектора, из-за этого спринг при создании бина соединения с со сфинкс выкидывает ошибку(что-то вроде ошибка уровня транзакции). Пробовал просто в maven проекте создать Connection вручную , все работает. Вот и до сих пор сижу не знаю уже что в application.properties прописать чтобы он корректно соединение открыл.

Comment: попробуйте прописать в конфиге Сфинкса mysql_version_string = 5.5.21